# Why request.GetResponse() throwing "remote server returned an error: (500) " on different port(!=80) urls?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webresponse

I am getting exception(The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.) for request.GetResponse() if I deploy application in different port other than 80(default), when I try to access the URL , it is working fine.

I had followed many suggestions from "Stackoverflow" and google. still I am getting the error with the below code

```
private bool Ping(string url, out string message)
    {
        message = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Timeout = 3000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
            request.Method = "HEAD"; 
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks,

Pavan

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an issue on the server side and should have nothing to do with your application.

That said, have you tried to access the same `url` from your computer / device (via chrome or IE) with the other port?

If it works on other devices, then you should check your device's setup; but I still think it's an issue on the server.